# Secure module usage in play framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework

After going through the sample program of Play, I was trying to create an application that would use the secure module to authenticate users as well as accept users via LinkedIn authentication.

In the code I call Security.connected() which returns the username. How do I set it for a person who has logged in through LinkedIn?. Is there a method to do so in the secure module, or should I use the session.put/get calls and check all around the code if the user logged in through LinkedIn or directly through the Secure module.

Thanks. I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the LinkedIn [module?](http://www.playframework.org/modules/linkedin)

Comment: Yes. I used the linked in module and the reference code. Before incorporating the linkedin module, I used the Security.connected() API to get the user info. With the linkedin module suggested approach, should I change the usage to Session.current().put("username", username); and session.get('username'); or is there anyway to continue to use the Security.connected() method. Essentially when user logs in thro linkedin